# Moose attribute initialization

Tags: perl, validation, moose

What is the typical approach for custom initialization of certain attributes when using Moose?

For instance, suppose I take two dates in string format as input to my class:

```
has startdate  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
has enddate    => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str');
```

These dates come in as strings, but I need them formatted in a specific date format (ISO8601), without Moose I would just initialize them in `new()` but I am unsure about with Moose.

It seems that the viable options from reading the docs are in `BUILDARGS`, `BUILD`, or using coercion. Which of these would be most appropriate given that I have a function `_format_as_iso8601()` that can take a date and return it formatted correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BUILD` is called after the constructor, which makes it handy to verify state but not necessarily useful to format incoming arguments.

`BUILDARGS` would let you modify incoming arguments before the constructor is called, which makes it a better fit for this case. Your attribute is read-only, so this could work.

But... if you're hungry for static typing, why would you stop after promising "this is a string"? If you create a [subtype](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Types#SUBTYPES) for ISO8601 strings, you can promise "this is a string *and* it has X format". Even better, you're doing that in a way that's immediately and trivially portable to other attributes.

I rather doubt the regex below will work for you, but I hope it will get the point across:

```
#define the type
subtype 'iso8601',
    as 'Str',
    where { /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ },
    message { "Not a valid ISO8601 string ($_)" };

#provide a coercion
coerce 'iso8601',
    from 'Str',
    via { _format_as_iso8601 $_ };

#tell moose to coerce the value
has startdate  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'iso8601', required => 1, coerce => 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just the type of solution I was hoping existed.

Comment: My Types::XSD has a built-in Date type constraint. Here's [an example coercing from a string](https://gist.github.com/tobyink/9280334). The type is parametrizable, allowing you to use type constraints like `Date[minInclusive => '1970-01-01']`.

Comment: @tobyink That is really cool, I am definitely going to go that route, it seems the most flexible without me building something out.